# EF 6 Optimisitic Concurrency Client-wins fails to retrieve data from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.2 in a windows service to pull data from my DB (using a DB first methodology), send that data to another system, then mark the record(s) as sent, and finally save them back to the DB.

When I save them back to the DB, I frequently get an update concurrency exception.  In the catch, I've chosen a client-wins methodology as Microsoft recommends here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/concurrency#resolving-optimistic-concurrency-exceptions-as-client-wins.

In the catch, the entry.GetDatabaseValues() returns null as if EF can't find the record in the DB.  This isn't inserting new records, but rather updating a single field in a preexisting record.

The exception doesn't occur for every record updated, a good 1 out of 3 or 4.

Also, there is a webpage that does very frequent inserts/reads into the db, but no updates.

Here is my code:

```
using (DCS db = new DCS(server.ConnectionString))
{
      AutotimeSOAP.CONTROLAREA soapControlArea = new AutotimeSOAP.CONTROLAREA();
      AutotimeSOAP.DATAAREA soapDataArea = new AutotimeSOAP.DATAAREA();
      AutotimeSOAP.InterfaceService2PortTypeClient autotime = CreateAutotimeClient(config.Credentials);

      if (System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol == (SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls))
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

      List<WintermTransactionArchive> WTMs = db.WintermTransactionArchives.Where(x => x.SentToDCSQueue == false && String.Compare(x.FunctionNumber, "30") < 0).OrderBy(x => x.TransactionTime).ToList();

      foreach (WintermTransactionArchive singleWTM in WTMs)
      {
            WintermTransactionArchive previousWTM = null;

            previousWTM = db.WintermTransactionArchives.Where(x => x.EmployeeNumber == singleWTM.EmployeeNumber && x.TransactionID < singleWTM.TransactionID && String.Compare(x.FunctionNumber, "30") < 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionTime).FirstOrDefault();

            // clone to new object so that changes aren't persisted to the DB.
            WintermTransactionArchive clonePreviousWTM = (WintermTransactionArchive)previousWTM.Clone(); //performs memberwiseclone
            clonePreviousWTM.TransactionTime = singleWTM.TransactionTime;

            .
            .   Send data to other service
            .
            
            singleWTM.SenttoDCSQueue = true;
            
            try
            {
                  db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                  var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                  DbPropertyValues dbValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
                  entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(dbValues);
            }
     }
}
```

It seems as if EF is losing track of what record it has in the store or how to find it in the DB.
Any suggestions on how I might overcome this issue?

**EDIT:**

WintermTransactionArchive.Clone() Function.

```
    public partial class WintermTransactionArchive : ICloneable
    {
        //public partial object Clone();

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear in your code which object is saved in the end. I assume it's `singleWTM` but it's not clear how it gets attached to the context.

Comment: What is your Clone() implementation?

Comment: @GertArnold, It is the singleWTM.  And after the singleWTM.SentToDCSQueue =true; I use HasChanges = db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges(), which reports that the context detects changes in the singleWTM.  Before the modification, the ChangeTracker returns false.

Comment: @JohnGlenn, I added my implementation of Clone() to the question.

Comment: Nothing in your code points at an obvious reason why `singleWTM`'s entry can't be found. The only reason would of course be that it's deleted in the short timespan between fetching and trying to save it. But as you say, there's nothing that deletes any.

Comment: But you may consider removing optimistic concurrency altogether. After all, if "client wins" then it doesn't need to know anything about it. Unless of course you want to log the event or have any other feedback.